# Why this But not limited to ? I think includes enough for this. Is it necessary to use but not limited to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Malpractice includes, but is not limited to: –    attempting to cheat in any way, including using notes of any kind from   any source.– helping another candidate to cheat.–    impersonating another candidate or having another candidate   impersonate you.– copying the work of another candidate.   – disrupting the test in any way. – reproducing any part of the test in any medium. – attempting to alter the data on the Test Report Form.

Comment: "But not limited to" is a common legal hedge which prohibits a miscreant from cheating in some way not explicitly mentioned in the list. Leave it in.

Comment: And since "includes" does not mean "limited to", this can be attributed to an idiom of legal jargon ("legalese") that does not carry any special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

When we use, **"But not limited to"**, we are just saying that the list doesn't include everything in the set, which in this case is **"Malpractice"**. Often used in legal terms or when describing rules, it simply means that you something not on the list can still be in the set, and it's up to common sense and reasonability to decide if it will be.